# Why are BackgroundWorker's WorkerReportsProgress and WorkerSupportsCancellation's default values false?

Tags: c#, performance, backgroundworker

Is there a performance penalty for using `BackgroundWorker`'s `WorkerReportsProgress` and `WorkerSupportsCancellation` set to `true`? Is there some other reason for them to be `false`?

`true` would be more logical because if you don't want to implement them - just don't. `true` won't harm you.

I'm thinking of encapsulating `BackgroundWorker`s in a class (so I won't forget setting these properties to true, and for some other stuff). But since the default values are `false`, perhaps that indicates some disadvantage to them being `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that they're only to inform a calling program that it can't call them.

Comment: A bit of a necro comment, but I believe this is true in the context of potential subclasses. Not all operations **can** be cancelled and not all operations **have** progress to report. For example a subclass `SingleFileDeletionWorker` could hide (via `new`) the `WorkerSupportsCancellation` property and have it readonly as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `BackgroundWorker`'s code `WorkerReportsProgress` set to `false` will prevent user code from calling `ReportProgress` method. `ReportProgress` method itself a quite fast, but calculating current presentage might take some time. So there is no big performance gap, I guess, but some ticks can be saved.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ispiro Ok, there are no disadvantages to them being `true` :)

Comment: See the second to last sentence in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026405/why-is-attributes-isdefined-missing-overloads - "I don't buy "they forgot", they never do." Since this seems so illogical - I assume there is a reason.

Comment: @ispiro the reason is quite logical - let users decide what values should be assigned. for some users default `false` values is what they want as they might never want to implement progress or cancellation support.

Comment: So they can simply not implement them. Having the values `true` won't bother them. But for someone who _does_ want to implement them - `false` _is_ a problem.

Comment: @ispiro well, it is not true. for example my code is getting `BackgroundWorker` from the 3rd party code. I need to know whether a cancelation is supported there. once the cancelation or the progress is supported I should behave in one way, if not - in another. for my code might be better to get `false` value, if the cancelation is supported, rather then `true` value, if the cancellation is not supported. the same with the progress - is it not really great when I expect the progress notifications, but never get them.

Comment: Perhaps add that to the answer. As it stands - the answer doesn't answer the question. (- Why are the defaults false?)

Comment: But this shouldn't have any effect on performance unless the programmer calls reportprogress().  So why have the value if all you have to do is not call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I've never noticed any degradation.  I use these a lot and nearly always set those values to true.  If there is a penalty, then it has to be more than offset by the functionality it provides.  If there's data supporting the opposite, I'd like to know about it.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Why the down vote?  It may not be what the OP is looking for, but I think it answers the question and it's not much different from ie.s